# EF context singleton appropriate in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, singleton

I've deployed an MVC App on IIS 7.5 that uses EF 4.0.  The EF context is encapsulated in a singleton that is shared throughout the app.  I did that because I thought that the app needed a single context to manage CRUD functions across all sessions.

This seems to work fine except I've got two issues that are plaguing me:

1. I find duplicate records in the database occasionally.  Note: I don't update records, I mark old records as deleted and write a new record to the DB.
2. Occasionally, EF looses the SQL Connection causing the entire application to crash, forcing me to recycle the app-pool.

Is it likely that these issues are caused by sharing the context?  Would it be better not to use the singleton pattern for EF's context?  Does using a singleton create a single point of failure for all Ajax requests from all users?

Thanks for any guidance...

```
  public class SharedNHREntitiesContext
```

{
    private readonly NHREntities _context;

```
// Static members are lazily initialized.
// .NET guarantees thread safety for static initialization.
private static readonly SharedNHREntitiesContext instance = new SharedNHREntitiesContext();

// Make the constructor private to hide it.
// This class adheres to the singleton pattern.
private SharedNHREntitiesContext()
{
  // Create the ObjectContext.
  _context = new NHREntities();
}

// Return the single instance of the ClientSessionManager type.
public static SharedNHREntitiesContext Instance
{
  get
  {
    return instance;
  }
}

public NHREntities Context
{
  get
  {
    return _context;
  }
}
```

}

Comment: _See Also: [Don't Use Singleton DataContexts](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2011/03/dont-use-singleton-datacontexts-entity.html) or [Entity Framework Context Lifetime Best Practices](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/02/07/entity-framework-context-lifetime-best-practices.aspx)_

Comment: Remember that ObjectContext is not thread safe.

Comment: Thanks for the references Brad.

Comment: I didn't know context was not thread safe...  that's a real problem.  Thanks Pawel.

Comment: Not really a problem considering it should be per web request. I am no EF expert but we use ISession in nHibernate with a per web request lifetime

Comment: I would setup a container to handle all of that for you.

Comment: OK I guess that's my issue.  I'll have to find a graceful way to revert this back to a context-per-request.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: @CrazyCoderz - not-thread-safe won't be an issue if I don't keep the same context across requests, another reason to back out of a singleton in this situation.  -- thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up:  I removed the singleton EF context from the code.  I have not had any errors in the week since I did that...  so, it seems a singleton context is not a good idea across invocations of the MVC controller.

That being said, I am still getting occasional duplicate rows so I still have some issues to resolve that don't involve the singleton.

Thanks to all those who helped me resolve this.